# How add and remove array without re-index array key in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a list of the checkbox when clicking on any checkbox than new array append (push) in the main array. If uncheck than remove but not change any index for the current array.

explain:-

Like:- When I click on the first checkbox than array like

```
0: ["2"]
```

Like:- When I click on the second checkbox than array like

```
0: ["2"]
1: ["3"]
```

Like :- When I click on four checkbox than array like

```
0: ["2"]
1: ["3"]
2: ["5"]
```

after than uncheck checkbox if I uncheck first tthe han I needed array

```
1: ["3"]
2: ["5"]
```

again I click on first checkbox than need array link

```
1: ["3"]
2: ["5"]
3: ["2"]
```

Not need to change any array index key

https://jsfiddle.net/tx63yjhg/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" value="6" />
<input type="checkbox" value="7" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var values = [];
var new_value = [];

$("input").on("change", function() 
{
  var $this = $(this);
  
  if ($this.is(":checked")) 
  {
   var new_data = [$this.val()];
   new_value.push(new_data);
  }
  else 
  { 
   //remove array when uncheck checkbox
  }
  console.log('new_value',new_value);
});
</script>
```

**How I can remove array and add again??**

Comment: Why are you having array of arrays? Why not a simple flattened array instead?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal :- I have multiple values in the array so I need array inside array

Comment: Okay. Can you post the realistic array then. In the example posted above after removing value you expect array to be, `1: ["3"], 2: ["5"]`. What shall be the value of `new_value[0]`

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal : If remove 0 index than 0 index is removed and this key does not assign any array index

Comment: Look at this example - `let arr = [1,2]; delete arr[0]; console.log(arr);`. See the array index is still there with an empty value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether you achieve the same using an array of arrays or not. You can instead try use an object like following.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" value="6" />
<input type="checkbox" value="7" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var values = [];
var new_value = {};
var counter = 0;

$("input").on("change", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  
  if ($this.is(":checked")) {
    new_value[counter++] = [$this.val()];
  } else { 
    Object.entries(new_value).forEach(([k,v]) => {
      if(v.includes($this.val())) delete new_value[k];
    });
  }
  console.log('new_value',new_value);
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**

For add

```
new_value[counter++] = {id1: 100, id2: 200, "id3": 300,"value":474}; // e.g. object
```

For remove

```
let valueToBeRemoved = 234; // e.g. value to be removed

Object.entries(new_value).forEach(([k,v]) => {
  if(v.value === valueToBeRemoved) delete new_value[k];
})
```

**EDIT 2**

```
for (var k in new_value) {
    if(new_value[k].value === valueToBeRemoved) delete new_value[k];
}
```

Comment: If array value like this than ?? new_value[counter++] = {id1: 100, id2: 200, "id3": 300,"value":value474};

Comment: @PraveenKumar - You can do it. However, we will need to update our delete code. Which property of the object defines the uniqueness of the object?

Comment: Nikhil  - Can you please update your answer with the object array delete

Comment: @PraveenKumar - I have updated my answer with add / edit block. Can you please check

Comment: @PraveenKumar - Glad to help you :)

Comment: Nikhil Aggarwal -  This code is not working on IE and safari browser. I think You need to update your answer according.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - Please see edit 2 - Object.entries and arrow function are not supported in IE. Updated the piece of code

Answer (score -1):

It easy:

```js
var values = [];

$("input").on("change", function() 
{
  var $this = $(this);
  var new_value = [];
  
  if ($this.is(":checked")) 
  {
   var new_data = [$this.val()];
   new_value.push(new_data);
  }
  console.log('new_value',new_value);
});
```